# Log4j SMTP Send Error Messages to E-Mail

Tags: java, smtp, log4j

I am having a major problem trying to get my Log4j to send SMTP e-mails when there is an issue.  Here is my code:

```
final Properties properties = new Properties();
final String strProperties = "log4j.rootLogger=ERROR, console, smtp\n"
            + "log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender\n"
            + "log4j.appender.console.Target=System.out\n"
            + "log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout\n"
            + "log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%-5p: %c - %m%n\n"
            + "log4j.appender.smtp=org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender\n"
            + "log4j.appender.smtp.EvaluatorClass=com.blah.blah.log4j.TriggerOnError\n"
            + "log4j.appender.smtp.SMTPHost=localhost\n"
            + "log4j.appender.smtp.From=mml_automation@blah.com\n"
            + "log4j.appender.smtp.To=ccmis@blah.com\n"
            + "log4j.appender.smtp.Subject=BagBox ERROR\n"
            + "log4j.appender.smtp.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout\n"
            + "log4j.appender.smtp.threshold=INFO\n"
            + "log4j.appender.smtp.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} : %-40c : %-5p %x - %m %n\n"
            + "log4j.logger.com.blah.blah.service.BagBoxService=INFO, smtp\n"
            + "log4j.logger.com.blah.blah.security=INFO, smtp\n"
            + "log4j.logger.org.springframework.core=ERROR, console, smtp\n"
            + "log4j.logger.org.springframework.beans=ERROR, console, smtp\n"
            + "log4j.logger.org.springframework.context=ERROR, console, smtp\n"
            + "log4j.logger.org.springframework.web=ERROR, console, smtp\n"
            + "log4j.logger.org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet=ERROR, console, smtp\n"
            + "log4j.logger.org.springframework.security=ERROR, console, smtp\n"
            + "log4j.logger.org.springframework.aop=ERROR, console, smtp\n"
            + "log4j.logger.org.springframework.ui=ERROR, console, smtp\n";

    final ByteArrayInputStream byteProperties = new ByteArrayInputStream(
            strProperties.getBytes());
    properties.load(byteProperties);
    PropertyConfigurator.configure(properties);
```

I keep getting the following error in my console:

```
Could not connect to SMTP host: localhost, port: 25;
  nested exception is:
java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable: connect
```

If I run telnet on the IP address, it comes back fine and can connect fine.  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your SMTP daemon is listening on a "real" IP such as 192.168.1.123 and thus not bound to `localhost` (127.0.0.1) as indicated in

```
log4j.appender.smtp.SMTPHost=localhost
```

What does `netstat -anpt | grep 25` tell you? Do you perhaps run SMTP on a port other than 25?

Cheers,

Comment: I actually got that working actually.  However, now I have a different problem. It won't send e-mails if there is a problem with log4j sending messages to the DB (ie if it cannot connect to mySQL).  Can the e-mail part of log4j still work if the database part fails?

Comment: That is impossible to answer specifically, without seeing your code and database appender config. In general, though, you may want to look into the [`FailoverAppender`](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html) and define the DB appender as your primary and SMTP as failover/secondary. Not sure it fits your use case precisely, but you could work from there.

Comment: I guess my question is, how would you send an e-mail if there is an error with log4j itself?  The reason it's not sending is because it is still the INFO level, but there is `log4j:ERROR JDBCAppender::append(), Not ready to append !`, so how would I e-mail that?

Comment: I wouldn't expect Log4j to be able to append to email if there is an error with Log4j itself. What did you expect?